# Dividing two running totals in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

I have three columns, store_id, opening_date and termination_date.

I want to write a query that performs this:

*total number of store terminated up until a specific date ÷ total number of stores opened up until that same specific date*

This would give me the fraction of the total stores opened that have been terminated at that point in time.

I want to calculate this over the span of every date from the first store opening until present day.

I have realized that in order to do this, I will have to divide two running totals (the running total of every store ever terminated ÷ the running total of every store ever opened), which has proven to be quite hard.

*NOTE: Every store has an opening date, but not every store has a termination date, as a large portion of the stores in this table have yet to be terminated*

If you are having trouble seeing what I mean, here is what a graph of the query would look like visually:
[image]

Here is the code I have gotten so far

```
SELECT 
approved_time as opening_date, churn_date as termination_date, 
sum(count(id)) over (order by  churn_date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)  as terminated_stores,
sum(count(id)) over (order by  approved_time asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as total_stores,
sum(count(id)) over (order by  churn_date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) / 
sum(count(id)) over (order by  approved_time asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS fraction_terminated

FROM STORES

GROUP BY churn_date,approved_date
```

The resulting table looks as follows, where the running total of  total stores is just 1,2,3,4,5 .... (which is not correct/what I want) and the resulting fraction is also not correct. The running sum of the terminated stores is correct however.
[image]

I have been struggling trying to solve this for a while, thank you for your help!

Comment: Show us your code to allow to improve it :)

Comment: I edited my post to add the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't count ids. As you don't want to count the nulls as terminated use the date column instead. You also need to specify that nulls are ordered first:

```
sum(count(churn_date))
    over (order by churn_date nulls first
          range between unbounded preceding and current row
) * 1.00 as terminated_stores
```

You'll want to avoid integer division so convert the numerator to a decimal value prior to computing the percentage. I changed to `range between` so it will count all store opens (closings) with the same timestamp together. And you do have to avoid divide by zero as well:

```
sum(count(close_dt)) over (
    order by close_dt asc nulls first
    range between unbounded preceding and current row
) * 1.00 /
nullif( sum(count(open_dt)) over (
    order by open_dt asc
    range between unbounded preceding and current row
), 0) as pct
```

See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48fa62/23

Comment: this works great for terminated stores, but how would i get the proper running some for total_stores as well? As you can see in the current query it is not returning what i want.

Comment: @Sean Well as far as I could determine, if you have a store listed then it's a given that it was also open. If not then make the same adjustment for those.

Comment: A stores opening date refers to the original date it was opened, while termination date refers to the date it was permanently closed. so in theory a store could be listed but would have closed  down at a later date if that makes sense.

Comment: If every row has an open date then it does not matter whether which of the two columns you use for counting. Are you going to have ties in the open date column?

Comment: hey i saw your update, i am going to give it a try!

Comment: @Sean, make sure you get the latest update. I think I'm finished though.

Comment: It looks right, I am just going to quickly test it on my data, and I will update you after that, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: so unfortunatlely i only have select access in my database so i am unable to do the "with" statement you put, so i am trying to find a work around

Comment: hey, so I worked around the issue, but unfortunately I got this error "postgresql error: RANGE clause of window functions not yet implemented". I am guessing that might be an issue with the postgreSQL version I am using (I am not sure tho). I found this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66114/range-clause-error-within-window-function, so I will give this solution a shot.

Comment: It can definitely be rewritten with subqueries.

Comment: @Sean btw the only need to use `range` vs `rows` is because of the way I figured you would want to treat ties (same open/close dates). If that doesn't apply then you can probably switch that back.